# implementing the Endless Adapter

Tags: android, cwac-endless, endlessadapter

I get the entire data from the Server by using doInBackground() method as shown below.

```
class DataLoader extends Activity{

    public void onCreate()
    {
         ...............................
          new AsyncTask1().execute();
    }

    class AsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DataLoader.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }


            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                JSONObject json;

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",datafield1));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2",datafield2));
                    json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

                try {

                    int success = json.getInt(SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {

                        products = json.getJSONArray(PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(ID);
                            String price = c.getString(PRICE);
                            String name = c.getString(NAME);


                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(PID, id);
                            map.put(PRICE, price);
                            map.put(NAME, name);

                           ..................

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);

                        }
                        return "success";
                    }
                    else {
                        // no materials found for this section

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

                if( msg != null && msg.equals("success"))
                {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */

                        customadapter=new CustomAdapterList(DataLoader.this, productsList);        
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }
                });

                }
            }
        }
```

As per the above code, I am setting the data to the `listview` in the `onPostExecute()` method only after the entire data is loaded. But now I want to implement the `CW Endless Adapter` with the present code, but as I am new to this, I am unable to get how to move on from here. I included the CWAdapter jar file in the libs folder. Have referred [this](http://droidista.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/using-cwacs-endlessadapter-with-custom.html) and searched a lot , but no use. Can some one please help me implementing the endless feature for the data I get?

Comment: What is your exact problem? Implenting a custom adapter is very simple.

Comment: My question is not about custom adapter. I have done the custom adapter already. But I want to add Endless Adapter feature to it. Moreover is there a way to get the data from the server and simultaneously set the data to the listview by using endless adapter rather than waiting for the entire data to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic Idea is to run an `AsyncTask` when more data is required, that is when uses scrolls to bottom of the list. Here's a [quick demo project](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b4d3597e913327afadd5).

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems good. But I am unable to understand with the details you provided. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this. BTW you mentioned this as  //---paged query for specific set....... in your code. But I wrote the php code to return the entire data what's there in the database. Can you please point me to some links where I can get this paged query examples in php? Thanks.

Comment: @user2056532 There are [many examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm) on [the Internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+paging).

Comment: I am stuck at this ArrayAdapter<Employee> class badly. How to prepare that class? I know how to make customAdapter by extending BaseAdapter. But what's this? Can you please reply me?

Comment: @Sam Extend `ArrayAdapter<K>` where K is the class of objects you want to hold in adapter. Updated answer.

Comment: please look at this small [code snippet](http://pastebin.com/kEUy47Fk). This is the way I have to do it. Right? Please confirm. And how to access the result arraylist in adapter to set the each arraylist item to the views? I know I have been pestering you, but I have to submit this academic project to my university in two days :( Please do me this last help.

Comment: @Sam I'd make a demo project.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are my hero.

Comment: I was struggling with this since two days. Your demo project helped a lot, and now my adapter is running nicely. thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information than just a link as links sometimes do not work but a simple explanation here would have been of a lot of help. Thanks